# Read a JSON object using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, json.net

Sorry but I'm at a loss.  I'm trying to loop the following JSON object using Newtonsoft so that I can process some code

```
      [{"FirstName":"Andrea","Middlename":"M.","LastName":"Smith"},{"FirstName":"Ronald","Middlename":"E.","LastName":"Jones"}]
```

What I need is a simple loop that will read the names and send to a database.  So I want to

```
    For  .....
    Dim FirstName as string = 
    Dim Middlename =""
    Dim LastName = ""

    Send to data base FirstName + " " + MiddleName + " " + LastName
    Loop
```

Thanks for the help and if this is listed somewhere else I have not been able to find it

Comment: Search for “newtonsoft json deserialize array vb.net” and you’ll find plenty of examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28400404/125981 perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Worked out my own answer.  First created a class

```
       Public Class Person
       Public FirstName As String
       Public MiddleName As String
       Public LastName As String
       End Class
```

Then

```
     Dim JObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Person())(JSON)
```

Then

Looped it

```
        For i = 0 To JObject.Length - 1
        firstname = JObject(i).FirstName
        Next
```